# How to get result a sparql query in text format in python

Tags: python, sparql, endpoint

I want to fetch the results of my sparql query in text format not in json, xml and etc in this python code. Actually, I need just the value of the object in string/text.

```
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")
sparql.setQuery("""
    SELECT ?p ?o
    WHERE {  <http://dbpedia.org/page/Eurobike> ?p ?o . 
    filter langMatches(lang(?o),"en")
    }
""")
sparql.setReturnFormat(XML)
results = sparql.query().convert()
print(results.toxml())
```

Comment: the you should just get the values out of the corresponding formats. How to get the values per variable is also in the documentation https://github.com/RDFLib/sparqlwrapper - so it's unclear where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like CSV or TSV.

```
setReturnFormat(CSV)
```